# Why do I get 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'?

Tags: python, numpy

I currently working on a machine learning project, and I implemented data augmentation by myself for some reason.

The type of image is

> 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'

And I'd like to append my image to list called images.

```
#method "scale_augmentation" is self defined function. Return image.
f_processed = self.scale_augmentation(image = f) 

#error occurs here                
self.images.append(Image.fromarray(f_processed.convert('RGB'), dtype=np.float32) / 255.)
```

I'm stuck with this error for so long and I've gone through many stack overflow questions regarding to this error. 
Thanks in advance.

---

Scale_augmentation function looks like this

```
def scale_augmentation(image, scale_range=(256, 400), crop_size=224):
scale_size = np.random.randint(*scale_range)
image = imresize(image, (scale_size, scale_size))
image = random_crop(image, (crop_size, crop_size))
return image
```

---

Also error looks like this

```
--> 100 self.images.append(Image.fromarray(f_processed.convert('RGB'), dtype=np.float32) / 255.)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Comment: Because a `numpy.ndarray` is not an `Image`. you probably want to call `convert` on the `Image` object.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for your reply! I'm new to ml, sorry for my beginner question. I though f_processed is Image, so I call convert('RGB') on Image, not ndarray. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should check that is true. Some operation might return an array instead of the image object. Just check `type(f_processed)`.

Comment: @Graipher type was <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>. I also added scale_augmentation function on question form. Could you look at it?

Comment: You'll need to add one or more `type` checks on `f_processed` or `image` till you find where you start to get `ndarray` instead of the expected `Image`.  Since you haven't provided full working code, only you can add those debugging tests.

Answer (score 3):

First convert it to image object by `Image.fromarray` then use `convert`

Try this:

`self.images.append((Image.fromarray(f_processed, dtype=np.float32).convert('RGB') / 255.)`

Clear steps are:

`image = Image.fromarray(image)`

`image = image.convert("RGB")`

now image is in jpeg format and you do:

`image.save('test_test.jpeg')`

Comment: what is `Image`?